# Calculate the sum $\sum_{k=0}^{p}\binom{p-1+k}{p-1}x^{k}$

Tags: combinatorics

Let $p>5$ a natural number and let $x$ be a rational number, $0<x<1$. Would anyone know how to calculate the following sum:
$$\sum_{k=0}^{p}\binom{p-1+k}{p-1}x^{k}?$$

Comment: Any conditions on $p?$

Comment: Consider $p>3$, $p$ natural number.

Comment: @thebalans So did you get the concept of negative binomial series?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint :

Coefficient of $t^{p-1}$ in $$\left( (1+t)^{p-1}x^0+ (1+t)^{p}x^1+(1+t)^{p+1}x^2\ldots +(1+t)^{2p-1}x^p\right) $$

Which is a finite GP which can be summed easily.

Comment: The sum is: $$(1+t)^{p\text{−}1}\left[1+(1+t)x^{1}+(1+t)^{p+1}x^{2}+\cdots+(1+t)^{p}x^{p}\right]\\=(1+t)^{p\text{−}1}\left[\frac{(1+t)^{p+1}x^{p+1}-1}{(1+t)x-1}\right]=\frac{(1+t)^{2p}x^{p+1}-(1+t)^{p\text{−}1}}{(1+t)x-1}.$$ How can I get the coefficient of $t^{p-1}$?

Comment: @thebalans Use the negative binomial series for the denominator to get your answer.  Refer to  
  http://mathworld.wolfram.com/NegativeBinomialSeries.html

Comment: Following your idea, if I'm not wrong, I've got: $$\sum_{k=0}^{p}\binom{p-1+k}{p-1}x^{k}=\frac{x^{p+1}}{\left(x-1\right)^{p-1}}-\left(-1\right)^{p}x^{p+2}$$

Comment: @thebalans Well that's good.  I can't confirm whether you are right or not because I have not tried to find the answer, I just give hints.  But I think the answer might be correct.